# Query em JPQL para inserção de Dados

Tags: java, query, jpa, sql-insert, jpql

Como posso inserir um dado com JPQL contendo valores:

```
 @Query("insert into user values()")
    User insertUser();
```

**Dados:** 
    nomeUsuario
    emailUsuario

Comment: Quando for criar questões, pense bem nas tags. Ter esquecido de colocar as tags [java] e [jpa] era pedir para não receber boas respostas, vez que há muitas pessoas que recebem notificações de conteúdos por tags e a sua pergunta não seria notada por algumas pessoas aptas a te responder. Já adicionei as tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dessa Forma:

```
String query = "insert into User values(?,?)";

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.createNativeQuery(query)
   .setParameter(1, "maria")
   .setParameter(2, "123456")
   .executeUpdate();
```